# How to use RoboSpice cache types

Tags: android, caching, robospice, lru, android-lru-cache

*Note: this is general question of person new to caching mechanisms on Android.*

Why RS uses LRU caching in [FlickrSpiceService](https://github.com/octo-online/RoboSpice-samples/blob/63778866d7ee836ca6a8099fb8ebb9f6401cd3f8/robospice-sample-image-caching/src/com/octo/android/robospice/sample/service/FlickrSpiceService.java) sample?

There is `LruCacheBitmapObjectPersister`:

```
@Override
public CacheManager createCacheManager(Application application) throws CacheCreationException {
    CacheManager manager = new CacheManager();
    InFileBitmapObjectPersister filePersister = new InFileBitmapObjectPersister(getApplication());
    LruCacheBitmapObjectPersister memoryPersister = new LruCacheBitmapObjectPersister(filePersister, 1024 * 1024);
    manager.addPersister(memoryPersister);
    return manager;
}
```

Why don't remove it and just use `InFileBitmapObjectPersister` like this:

```
@Override
public CacheManager createCacheManager(Application application) throws CacheCreationException {
    CacheManager manager = new CacheManager();
    InFileBitmapObjectPersister filePersister = new InFileBitmapObjectPersister(getApplication());
    manager.addPersister(filePersister);
    return manager;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Memory cache (the `LruCacheBitmapObjectPersister` in this case) is much faster than the file system one (`InFileBitmapObjectPersister`), but at the same time, it is smaller.

Therefore, using smaller (but faster) memory cache as Level 1 and larger (but slower) file system cache as Level 2 offers improved performance for common usage. You can check [this broadly related answer for processor cache](https://superuser.com/questions/695632/why-do-we-need-multiple-levels-of-cache-memory) for more info. Multilevel cache is a recurring theme in Computer Science.